External magnetic field in Quantum Espresso?
How can I apply an external magnetic field in Quantum Espresso?
I want to apply an external magnetic field to a 2D monolayer graphene.

I am not sure if this is outdated but this is a little old response from Nicola Marzari in Quantum ESPRESSO user forum:

[I]f indeed you want to apply an external magnetic field, that is not
possible (in most codes - see the paper by Wei Cai and Giulia Galli
PRL 2005 or so on how this could be done).
Codes can calculate the Berry phase magnetization, or can apply
a magnetic dipole, and you might use these tools for your goals,
but you can't flat out apply it (due to PBCs, and the fact that you
cannot use an approach that mirrors the electric enthalpy (Souza
and Vanderbilt, Umari and Pasquarello, both in PRL 2001)).
Last - the suggestion of imposing a total magnetization can be used to
force the solution in a magnetic system to have a desired total
magnetization, but that's not imposing a magnetic field.

The PRL papers mentioned in the quote appear to have mistakes in the years. It is likely that Marzari intended the following papers:

Wei Cai and Giulia Galli, "Ab Initio Calculations in a Uniform Magnetic Field Using Periodic Supercells", Phys. Rev. Lett. 92, 186402 (2004)
Ivo Souza, Jorge Íñiguez, and David Vanderbilt, "First-Principles Approach to Insulators in Finite Electric Fields", Phys. Rev. Lett. 89, 117602 (2002)
P. Umari and Alfredo Pasquarello, "Ab initio Molecular Dynamics in a Finite Homogeneous Electric Field", Phys. Rev. Lett. 89, 157602 (2002)

